# Installing caffe brings up some questions, depending libraries and versions

Tags: installation, cmake, makefile, libraries, caffe

I wanted to install caffe on openSuse.
Just for the record - it worked out for me, I just don't know what's the "exact" way to do this. The things I did maybe aren't really for someone who's new to this, and also it was kind of a "bad installation". My way was the following:

First, I did

```
make all
```

This worked, until it complained that some libraries weren't found (libclbas etc.). So I used

```
ccmake .
```

to change the paths to the libraries manually. I needed to manually type the paths to the snappy, boost_python, blas, cblas and lapack libs. After doing that I did

```
cmake .
```

and then

```
make
```

and everything worked. My problem now is - why doesn't make find the libs, and is there a way to fix this? I think the problem was that I didn't have /usr/lib/libcblas.so but /usr/lib/libcblas.so.3, and similar "problems" with the other libraries.

Another thing - when I tried using ccmake/cmake right from the beginning (without the make part first), there weren't any files in my build directory (like $CAFFE_ROOT/build/examples or $CAFFE_ROOT/build/tools were empty), so the mnist tutorial for example wasn't working. That's why I first called

```
make all
```

, what may seem strange to you.

Of course I know how to fix this stuff, but I would like to know how the correct way for a "clean and simple installation" is. Did is miss anything when using make/cmake, is this some kind of inconsistency in caffe or something else? And, what *is* the clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at the Ubuntu installation guide? http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html

It mentions all the different packages you might need. I couldn't find openSuse installation instructions - but you should be able to translate the `apt-get` commands for your platform.

Comment: Of course I did, just that they can't exactly be translated. Like mentioned before, make doesn't find the libraries if they are a newer version (I had libcblas.so.3, caffe was looking for libcblas.so and found nothing - so I had to use ccmake, so I could specify the exact path plus filename, for a simple example). I had to do a lot stuff on my own, without guide, including using both make and ccmake/cmake. But I already told that in the question above.

Comment: Why don't you contribute an install guide to Caffe for openSuse!